# Reciting the 'Yehi Ratzons' in Eizehu Mekoman on Erev Yom Kippur

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, shacharis-morning-prayer, korban, korbanos-ketores-prayers

As part of the recitation of the *mishnayot* of *eizehu mekoman* during *shacharit*, some *siddurim* print a *yehi ratzon* prayer after each of *mishnayot* 3 - 7, asking that G-d consider our recitation of these *mishnayot* as if we had actually brought the sacrifice discussed therein.

My Artscroll siddur (Ner Naftali, 2007) contains these prayers, with a note that they are omitted on *shabbat* and *yom tov*. The *yehi ratzon* after mishna 6, which deals with the *korban todah*, is additionally to be omitted on *erev pesach*, *pesach* itself and *erev yom kippur*.

The *siddur* does not explain why, but I presume that it is because individual sacrifices were not brought in the Temple on *shabbat* and *yom tov*, and, in addition, a *korban todah* (which contained *chametz* loaves as an accompaniment) was not brought on *chol hamoed pesach*, or *erev pesach*, where the prohibition of eating *chametz* after the 4th hour would limit the time available to eat of the (loaves accompanying the) *korban*. This is also the reason we (Ashkenazim) do not say *mizmor letodah* on any of these days.

My question is about *erev yom kippur*. I understand that we don't say *mizmor letodah*, or the *yehi ratzon* for the *todah*, because the *todah* could not be brought on *erev yom kippur*, when the start of the fast in the evening would limit the time for eating the *korban* (which could normally be eaten during the night following the day on which it was brought).

But why does Artscroll imply that one does say the *yehi ratzon* for the *chatat*, *asham* and *shelamim*? None of these could be brought on *erev yom kippur* either. (See [Mishna Berura 604:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%93) for confirmation.)

Does anyone know Artscroll's source for making a distinction between the *yehi ratzon* for *todah* and those for other *korbanot hane'echalot* with respect to *erev yom kippur*, or is this simply an error?

Comment: Todah comes with lots and lots of bread, the others don't so they're easier to eat.  And maybe an additional factor for chatat and asham is that you want to get those korbanot in before Yom Kippur to help you in your teshuvah.

Comment: Isn't it in relation with the fact that we don't make private requests to Hashem on the Shabbat and holidays?

Comment: @Heshy I don't follow. One can't bring chatat or asham on erev yom kippur, just as much as one can't bring todah. Why would one say the yehi ratzon for chatat and asham, but not todah?

Comment: @Kazibácsi That's fine for shabbat and yom tov, but why omit the yehi ratzon for todah on erev yom kippur (which is neither shabbat nor yom tov) but still say them for chatat and asham?

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46445&st=&pgnum=94&hilite=